# winforms app written in win7 looks different on win xp. why?

Tags: winforms, windows-7, windows-xp

I have written a simple app in winforms (.net 4.0) on win 7. Application looks how I want but when I tried it on windows xp everything looks different.

I have created a sample example to show how it looks on win 7 and xp.
What can I do to have the same look on both systems? 
The problem is not only with the background and font color but with the controls too. Here I show how the numericupdown looks but with table layout I have problem too.

[image: win 7]
[image: win xp]

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.numericUpDown1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numericUpDown1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // numericUpDown1
        // 
        this.numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 2;
        this.numericUpDown1.Increment = new decimal(new int[] {
        1,
        0,
        0,
        131072});
        this.numericUpDown1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 26);
        this.numericUpDown1.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0});
        this.numericUpDown1.Name = "numericUpDown1";
        this.numericUpDown1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(54, 22);
        this.numericUpDown1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 82);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(226, 99);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "groupBox1";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(407, 331);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.numericUpDown1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numericUpDown1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

I have no modified the xp color themes.
I have the same result on two diffrent computers with win xp.

Comment: Screenshots suck to debug code.  Copy and paste the code of  InitializeComponent().  And document if the Windows theme colors were modified on XP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
```

These are the statements that cause your trouble.  I'll pick-off the easy one first, don't make the BackColor of the form the same as the caption color.  If you want to pick a theme color then only choose the "Control" color.  Albeit that you'll typically get the old battleship gray.  Picking a neutral pastel color is your best bet but honoring the user's preference will never get you into trouble.

The AutoScaleDimensions property is auto-generated, based on the video adapter's DPI setting.  Which is different the XP machine.  You've got 120 dots-per-inch on your dev machine, 96 DPI (the default) on XP.  On Win7, that's set by the widget that looks like a ruler, Control Panel + Display, "Set custom text size (DPI)".

The AutoScaleMode property is correctly set to Font.  This ensures that all controls are automatically scaled to fit the font size.  Which is *larger* on your Win7 machine because of the higher DPI setting.  Accordingly, the form and its controls shrink on the XP machine.  The problem with the NumericUpDown control is that its a bit buggy (in more than one way), it doesn't scale the up/down glyphs properly.  They are proportionally too large, not leaving enough room for the text portion.  Simply making it a bit wider solves the problem.

Auto-scaling is fairly ugly, it is rarely 100% perfect.  The best thing to do is to switch your dev machine to 96 dpi.  A very common setting, still today.  Scaling *up* almost always works better than scaling down.

Answer (score 2):

`this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;`

There's your problem.  The color is going to be dependent on the operating system.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.activecaption.aspx

Consider setting an explicit color value (e.g. one of the `System.Drawing.Color` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx enumerations) instead.  Won't look exactly the same, but it will be closer.