# Controls moving in  vs2008 design mode on build

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a C#.NET winforms project, and some controls are moving in design view whenever I build the project.  Its only some of the controls (a panel with a label and datagridview in it, a button, a link button and a label) are all moving up on each build.

Has anyone seen this before or know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any add-ins installed? Can you copy the form into a new C# project and duplicate the behavior?

Comment: @SpectralGhost -Some add-ins.  Autocode v4.0 (disabled), Devart SQL COmplete (disabled), rockscroll (disabled), Smart Paster 2008 (enabled), TestDriven.Net 3.0 Personal (disabled), TestDriven.Net Reflector (enabled).

Comment: Are the controls standard WinForms or 3rd party?  Can you post reproducible demo code somewhere?

Comment: @Phil -See original question, I state what the controls are.

Comment: @Phil -Copying the controls into a new form does not show the moving behavior.

Comment: Does that mean you've fixed your problem?

Comment: @Phil -Nope.  But i can't recreate it in a new form.  So I have no idea what else to try.

Comment: So if you create a copy of your form doesn't that fix it?  I assume you have VS2008 SP1?  Can you move to 2010?

Comment: @Phil -I suppose I could get the express edition, but that's not really solving the problem...

Comment: Just so I understand your workflow...  do you position the controls on the form using the Designer, then build, and the controls are moved to a different position?

Comment: @SteveWong -Correct.  The controls are NOT added dynamically or anything like that.

Comment: Is the .Location property of the moving controls data bound to a configuration value?

Comment: Try this: 1) position one label correctly in the Designer (say, "labelName").  2) open YourForm.designer.cs, 3) find this.labelName.Location = (x, y).  4) build, 5) check this.labelName.Location = (x, y) again.  Are they the same?  Now open the form in the Designer again.

Comment: I'm sure you have already checked, but Anchor/Dock property?

Comment: Ok my guess. Are you sure that you do NOT have the Build key command (ie Ctrl + Shift + B) mapped to another command or more than one command (Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard)?

Comment: What happens if you lock the controls (Locked = True) do they still move then?

Comment: @JeremyThompson -Locked has no effect on the issue.

Comment: @JeremyThompson -Don't have any custom key mapping.  Also, usually don't just build, normally debug, then when I build use the menu.

Comment: @Steve -The controls in question do NOT all have the same dock/anchor properties, and some of them do have the same values as controls which are not moving.

Comment: @SteveWong -Control size/location is not bound to anything I know of.  Just positioned by drag and drop in the designer.

Comment: Do the controls stretch/shrink, or randomly move?  Could be related to AutoScaleDimensions from Hans comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872251/build-changes-button-size-property

Comment: @SteveWong -They move only.  Ok, my file show `this.AutoScaleDImensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F)`, but a fresh project shows `...(6F, 13F)`.  So... what does this mean?

Comment: Maybe we're getting closer.  What's the AutoScaleMode of the form?  Maybe try setting that to Inherit (or None for a test)?

Comment: @SteveWong -Its set to `Font`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the AutoScaleDimensions. My guess is that your form was originally created on another machine.

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscaledimensions%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> "The AutoScaleDimensions property represents the DPI or font setting
>   of the screen that the control was scaled to or designed for.
>   Specifically, at design time this property will be set by the Windows
>   Forms designer to the value your monitor is currently using. Then,
>   when the form loads at run time, if the CurrentAutoScaleDimensions
>   property is different from the AutoScaleDimensions, the
>   PerformAutoScale method will be called to perform scaling of the
>   control and all of its children. Afterwards, AutoScaleDimensions will
>   be updated to reflect the new scaling size."

My guess is that for odd some reason when you build you project property (maybe some others) gets adjusted, but not on design time.
I think about few possible reasons:

- You work on multiple monitors and/or there is some odd stuff with your adapter.
- There is some problem with auto-generated designer file. Maybe it
  edited manually somehow.

To fix I propose to do something I would do:

- Recreate form from scratch if possible, by copy-pasting bits
  one-by-one.
- If not take some merging tool and insert fresh form
      properties.

Also here is another interesting question on [AutoScaleDimentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364903/winforms-app-written-in-win7-looks-diffrent-on-win-xp-why).