# move .net form application to another OS make an appearance issue (from windows 7 to XP)

Tags: .net, winforms

I write .net windows application using .net 3.5 f/w with VS2008 with windows 7 platform OS as a development machine and it is working fine.

But when i run it on another machine that has Windows XP, many problem in appearance occur for example:

1. Background image of the form has disappeared .
2. Datagridview header has turned into another color (black)
3. Background of labels whichI set it as transparent will has a an unintended color .

I read about similar problem in this post 
[winforms app written in win7 looks different on win xp. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364903/winforms-app-written-in-win7-looks-diffrent-on-win-xp-why)

but I don't know what can I do

On Windows 7

[image: On Windows 7]

---

On Windows XP

[image: On Windows XP]

Comment: What can you do about what ? you should be more specific, there are multiple approaches depending what you want to get

Comment: hi  emecas

i want to write my app on my development machine (windows 7) and it work on windows xp in similar appearance , not necessary the same but accepted one . for example: if the datagridview header is all in black color how can the user read columns titles ? i wish if i can attach the image that show the differences between the two OSs

Comment: OK, what about if you show (in a picture by example) those specific details that look different and you would like to solve, so it will make easier to define an approach

Comment: how can i send this picture to you

Comment: I meant include it in the question

Comment: the details about the differences is almost what i mention is my post above, but if you still want the example pics, how can i send it to you because i have registered  just today and do not have any reputation?? am i understand what you mean because my English is not very good???? @emecas

Comment: i will send the two cases

when i develop form on windows 7 it's fine and look like this: http://www.4shared.com/download/G3QJqR2Oba/onwin7.png?lgfp=3000

but when i deploy it to windows XP it will look like this: http://www.4shared.com/download/WdzhVMVGce/onwinXP.png?lgfp=3000

Comment: @falconeagle It seems that a lot of the issues in the image above are to do with your colour preferences. Did you use the "System" colours? If so, those will vary from one machine to another. Try avoiding them if you want your app to look the same regardless of user preference.

Comment: That's not the way XP windows normally look.  Seems the user has installed a custom theme.  Having problems like this are to be expected.